# BIDS and SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services install

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, bids

We would like to start using SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services in our company, but we are using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Database Engine on a standalone server and have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate on our programming PCs.

From what I understand, we **need** Visual Studio 2008 for BIDS to install. Is it necessary that the SQL Server 2008 Database Engine **AND** Visual Studio **2008** be on THE SAME machine to install BIDS?

Can I use any of the Visual Studio **2008** Express versions?

Comment: no its not like that the vs2010 and mssql2008 should be on same machine

Comment: paste your problem here what exactly you want

Comment: According to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsreportcontrols/thread/78bd6eb6-9d14-48e2-80eb-8c8e66b52534) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173767.aspx) it's not compatible. I've been told that I need Visual Studio 2008 for this. I have tried to install the Express version but still don't see BIDS.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, you don't need to install any version of Visual Studio 2008 **before** installing BIDS.

When you install the SQL Server 2008 R2 client tools on your PC, this will include a version of Visual Studio 2008 with the business intelligence components installed.

From memory the requirement for Visual Studio 2008 is due to an incompatibility between Visual Studio 2010 and the Integration Services project type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Express Visual Studio

No, you don't need to install the DB engine. When you run the install, BIDS is listed under "client components" (or similar). The SQL Server install routine will install VS Express for you too.

Comment: Under which Application installation Software is BIDS located in? I have tried to install Visual Basic 2008 from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/express/future/bb421473) on the PC where I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and I notice that the only app in the Start menu listed is "Visual Studio 2008 Remote Debugger (x64)"

Comment: So I get the SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Installation disc and select Client Components and find BIDS there? It will not install the Database Engine on my PC?

Comment: @Rick, Yes, use the SQL installation disk, and you will be able to select the components you want to install. Do not install the Database engine, but make sure select BIDS.